# Can java AWT work without X11 or wayland?

Tags: java, x11

I am setting up a home server on an old PC, but I am not using a server like apache, instead making a really basic one in java. I have got a extremely basic linux kernel compiled and working on it. But I want a gui along with my program. Is it possible for me to do it without installing X11 or wayland on my system?
Note: I dont have anything on my system apart from the necessary java files.

Comment: If you wish to use AWT then there won't be any way arround some X11 server. It might be a VNC X11 server if you don't wish to have local access, only remote.

Comment: @AndréSchild Is there some other Java graphics library I should use or do I simply just need a graphics server?

Comment: The problem is, that you will need a driver for the grafic card in your system, which in turn can be used by AWT. I'm not aware of any such things

Answer (score 1):

You can run Java applications on **headless** mode on server environment.

From Oracle docs:

> ***Headless*** mode is a system configuration in which the display device, keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.

It means you can run some AWT graphic stuff, even without X11, but obviously, not visible in your screen. As example, you can create graphics with java.awt.Canvas and save/export as a image. Available AWT classes in headless mode are: Canvas, Font, Image (and subclasses), Print classes and Beep.

See detailed info here: [Headless Java SE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)